# Getting element ID from dynamic element using Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, revealing-module-pattern

I have a module that created some elements dynamically. Since they are created dynamically, I am having bind events using the static element `$('#data-container)` containing the dynamically created elements like so:

```
var $dataContainer = $('#data-container');
var $deleteProject = $('.delete-project');
$dataContainer.on('click', $deleteProject, _deleteProject);
```

Sooo.... I cannot use `$(this)` to get the `ID` if the button that I clicked. The context is `#data-container` and not the actual button that I clicked. I should also add that So, how can I do this? Here is my full code for better understanding:

```
var $dataContainer = $('#data-container'); // Container holding dynamic elements
var $deleteProject = $('.delete-project'); // Delete buttons for elements

$dataContainer.on('click', $deleteProject, _deleteProject);

function _deleteProject(){
  var project = $(this).attr('id'); // Doesn't work
  console.log(project);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID from the event argument. Try this. The event should always contain which target was clicked.

```
function _deleteProject(event){
  var id = event.target.id;
  var project = $(this).attr('id'); // Doesn't work
  console.log(project);
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you!